# how to customize UL element in Jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Im using Data filter for my list view, i want to change the height of the search box of ul.

```
<ul id="practiceList" data-role="listview"  data-split-theme="b" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Choose the item" data-filter-theme="e" data-divider-theme="e" data-dividertheme="f" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

CSS

```
 #page1.ui-content, #practiceList{
    min-height : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    margin     : 5px;
    padding    : 0;
}
#practiceList.ui-li {
    height : 70px;
}
#practiceList.ui-header .ui-title {margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;}
```

I can able to customize the LI elements to the listview using UL (id="practiselist"). But i can't customize the UL element. Here i need to change the height and width of the Placeholder i.e search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default jquery mobile styles.

```
.ui-input-search input.ui-input-text {
      height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the height and width of the elements in jquery mobile with pure css also...
Thing is that jquery mobile provides the environment for the design means the css is embedded into ur html code dynamically... So you can define the css by using **parent or children technique** in css...

For example,

```
#page ul.ui-listview { /*Your Style*/ }
#page ul.ui-listview li.ui-li { /*Your Style*/ }
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for reponse @Mahesh and SaurabhLP let me apply this code in my project and i will back to u